# Problem with the return type of Compile

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

**Can I return anything other than a real number with a compiled function ?**

In the example below, I use `Compile` on a toy function to illustrate my problem, the real function is actually much more complicated but returns a list with the same structure (using `Reap` and `Sow`, I don't even know if they are compilable...)

```
 Clear[compiledFunction];
compiledFunction =
 Compile[{{node, _Integer, 2}},
  Block[{resultList},
    (*Normally, 
    here is a complicated function that gives the list below*)
    resultList = {e, {{1.0469298976064088`, 
        0.2135758764321412`, -2.546929897606409`, \
-1.4878119246441033`}, {{{{3, 2.`}, {3, 2.`}, {6, 9}, {6, 6}, {3, 
           3}, {3, 3}}, -1.3515806860254191`}, {{{2.`, 3}, {3, 
           2.`}, {6, 9}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 
           3}}, -0.27572527085777865`}, {{{3, 3}, {2.`, 2.`}, {6, 
           9}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, 
         3.288072359129128`}, {{{3, 3}, {3, 2.`}, {5.`, 9}, {6, 
           6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}}, 1.3581802540879195`}}}} ;
    resultList
    ];]
trialNode = {{3, 3}, {3, 1}, {6, 9}, {6, 6}, {3, 3}, {3, 3}};
AbsoluteTiming[ompiledFunction[trialNode]]
```

**Error**

[image]

Comment: `Sort@Compile\`CompilerFunctions[]` returns the list of compilable functions.
You have to return a list of matrix of same types.
E.g., this will compile:
`compiledFunction = Compile[{{node, _Real, 2}}, Block[{resultList}, resultList = Flatten@{node, {3., 4.}}; resultList]]`

Comment: More explicitly, `Compile[]` does not support returning "ragged" lists like `{1., {2. ,3.}}`; they need to be vectors, matrices, etc. (i.e. `ArrayQ[]` should return `True` for them).

Comment: Moreover, ˋeˋ seems to be undefined. Did you mean ˋEˋ?